# How do I prevent Death Stranding from auto-equipping blood bags?

Tags: death-stranding

I want to save my blood bags for fighting BTs with hematic grenades. I rarely fall down, but once I do the game always equips a blood bag and starts giving me a transfusion even when I specifically and consciously did not have a bag equipped.

The description of the blood bag makes it sound as if new bags will only be switched if you empty an equipped bag, but this is not the behavior I'm seeing:

[image: In-game description of a Blood Bag.]

I have hundreds of cryptobiotes that I never get to eat because the game always wastes my blood bags by equipping one any time I so much as scrape a knee.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Not an answer, but as long as you don't play too badly, you'll never run out of blood bags. You get plenty of them every time you retreat to your safe house, and there's an NPC that gives you improved blood bags for every delivery you make. At some point I even stopped caring about getting injured, and I still had more blood bags than I knew what to do with them.

Comment: Yeah, it's not so much about being worried I'll run out of individual bags, because I can get them from resting like you said or they can be crafted (so you can really never run out even if you're the worst player).. It's just that I can only carry 4 bags (in the pouch) and when I come across a BT area, those 4 bags are worth X number of grenades.. And I want them for the grenades, not random papercuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's not possible in the current version.** If you have a blood bag anywhere on your character they will be automatically equipped and used. Keeping them in utility pouch only helps to reduce carried volume - they won't occupy "small" item slot on your backpack or suit.

You can work-around it by always keeping your blood bags in your vehicle nearby.

If you are worried about keeping enough grenades, later in the game you will be able to upgrade your backpack with additional grenades pockets.

Comment: As much as "don't carry any on you" sucks, it unfortunately seems like the only correct answer.